# Avoiding deadlock in reentrant code C++11

Tags: c++11, deadlock, reentrancy

I am working on refactoring some legacy code that suffers from deadlocks.  There are two main root causes:

1) the same thread locking the same mutex multiple times, which should not difficult to resolve, and 
2) the code occasionally calls into user defined functions which can enter the same code at the top level.  I need to lock the mutex before calling user defined functions, but I might end up executing the same code again which will result in a deadlock situation.  So, I need some mechanism to tell me that the mutex has already been locked and I should not lock it again.  Any suggestions?

Here is a (very) brief summary of what the code does:

```
class TreeNode {
public:
    // Assign a new value to this tree node
    void set(const boost::any& value, boost::function<void, const TreeNode&> validator) {
      boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(mutexToTree_);

      //  call validator here       

      boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> ulock(lock);

      // set this TreeNode to value
    }

    // Retrieve the value of this tree node
    boost::any get() {
      boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(mutexToTree_);

      // get value for this tree node
    }
private:
    static boost::shared_mutex mutexToRoot_;
};
```

The problem is that the validator function can call into `get()`, which locks  `mutexToRoot_` on the same thread. I could modify `mutexToRoot_` to be a recursive mutex but that would prevent other threads from reading the tree during `get()` operation, which is unwanted behavior.

Comment: Please edit your post to include an [MCVE] of the relevant code.

Comment: We need the code to understand the sequence of those threads and mutex. This case is about how the other person programmed that code and use mutex to "synchronize" threads. The mutex are useful but we must be careful that to not create death lock.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11 you can use [`std::recursive_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex), which allows the owning thread to call `lock` or `try_lock` without blocking/reporting failure, whereas the other threads will block on `lock`/receive `false` on `try_lock` until the owning thread calls `unlock` as many times as it called `lock`/`try_lock` before.

Comment: I thought about using recursive mutex, but this would mean that I would need to use all the way, even in those places where it is not appropriate.  I added some code that hopefully helps to illustrate the situation.